# Check if service is running?

Tags: c++, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Querying if a Windows Service is disabled (without using the Registry)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384284/querying-if-a-windows-service-is-disabled-without-using-the-registry)

I need to check if 'Event Log' services in running or not. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use OpenSCManager(), then OpenService(), then ControlService().

Comment: Here's a code sample that does more-or-less the same thing: https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/607dba810fa7fc1db761e4f0ad1fe464

Answer (score 0):

some example code for using the Win32 API can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686335(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You may execute

```
>sc query Eventlog
```

and examine the result.