# Querying if a Windows Service is disabled (without using the Registry)?

Tags: c#, service, registry

Is there a .NET (C#) method or API call that I can use to query if a Windows Service is disabled? The relevant MSDN article [is here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103000).

I want to avoid querying the registry directly. Below is some of the code that I am using right now (and it works). However I am looking for something more elegant and less invasive.

```
const String basepathStr = @"System\CurrentControlSet\services\";
String subKeyStr = basepathStr + servicenameStr;

using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKeyStr))
{
    return (int) key.GetValue("Start");
}
```

I did find a [simliar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939611/get-the-disabled-status-of-a-windows-service) but I was hoping for a better answer since the answers are presumably outdated (3 years have passed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This the most relevant section of the code I decided to use...thanks for the help all!

```
    StartupState state = StartupState.Unknown;
    try
    {
        PermissionSet fullTrust = new PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        fullTrust.Demand();
        string wmiQuery = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='" + servicenameStr + @"'";
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject service in results)
        {
            if (service["StartMode"].ToString() == "Disabled")
                state = StartupState.Disabled;
            else
                state = StartupState.Enabled;
        }
        return state;
    }
    catch (SecurityException se)
    {
        return StartupState.Refused;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StartupState.Error;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ServiceController` class to get information about services.

**EDIT**
Seems one of the things you can't do with the `ServiceController` is get the startup type. Googling showed the following blog post that has code that uses P/Invoke to get the service startup type: http://peterkellyonline.blogspot.de/2011/04/configuring-windows-service.html

Comment: Are your referring to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus.aspx ? If so, that tells me everything BUT whether the service is disabled...

Comment: As I wrote in my Edit, yes, I do refer to that class, but I'm also referring to an additional blog post that has information on how to use the `ServiceController` along with some native calls to get what you want without accessing the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ref to System.Management and the following code will get you the StartMode

```
        string wmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='YourServiceName'";
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
        var results = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject service in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(service["StartMode"]);
        }
```

Comment: Why do you loop over the results? Surely only one service with `YourServiceName` can be installed?

Comment: In my WPF project, which controls a service inside a custom `ServiceModel`, the above code just hangs forever when I try and iterate `results`.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceController class doesn't provide this information. You should use WMI. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7665/Extend-ServiceController-class-to-change-the-Start) for detailed solution

Answer (score -1):

**WMI** can be another way for querying the status of the windows services

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
```

And then link the service you want to view the satus by:

```
// Link by service name
ServiceController TheServiceName = new ServiceController();
TheServiceName.ServiceName = "Spooler";

// Link by display name
ServiceController TheDisplayName = new ServiceController();
TheDisplayName.ServiceName = "Print Spooler";
```

To check for example the isRunning Status :

```
if (TheServiceName.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    MessageBox.Show("The service is running.");
```

Comment: And if the service isn't running, just how is that code supposed to tell you if it is disabled or not? Not all services that aren't running are disabled, you know.