# How do I programmatically check if the MySQL service is running on Windows?

Tags: c++, mysql, service

I have a software automatically running as a service on windows platform, which depends on the MySQL database service.

But when the computer restarts, sometimes the software can't connect to MySQL if the MySQL service starts later than my software.

So how can I check whether the MySQL service is running in my software (using C++ language)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259291/check-if-service-is-running

Answer (score 0):

- Got to Start, search for "Services"
- Open the application
- Search MySQL (if 8 then its mysql80), right click and start.

Above steps are given, considering the fact you have to manually start the service.
If you just want to check that service is running, just check status of the above.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows, input the powershell with `Get-Service -Name 'mysql*'`. Then you can see the mysql status.